# Creating A High Voltage Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, high-voltage, high-current

I am currently building my own high voltage power supply running off of a **10v** input and a **360v** output. The circuit will use a 555 timer switching at a frequency **f** that will drive a MOSFET to power a transformer with a winding ratio of **1:36**. The output will then be fed into a full wave rectifier.

I would like to know how exactly the frequency of the 555 timer will affect the output voltage (I am thinking of using 60-120 Hz so the skin effect should be negligible), what effect using a PWM signal on a transformer will have, any changes I should make to the circuit, how I would be able to calculate the impedance of the drain and source of the MOSFET and since I am creating the transformer myself, what effect using a ferrite cage versus an open air transformer would have on the circuit.

The circuit will be used to charge up capacitors that powers a xenon flash lamp (triggered by an external source).

Comment: You'll probably want cheaper, lighter transformers --> higher frequencies. (Up to a point.) Probably not air-core. But instead I'd recommend looking at battery-powered emergency xenon flash-lamps. Their circuits are quite simple and effective. In their case, they are self-triggering by using an SCR and a trigger transformer to get the 4kV pulse to the strap around the xenon flashtube.

Comment: You can find some circuits [here](https://laser-caltech.web.cern.ch/report/Flash%20lamp%20Eg&G.pdf). Starting on page 12.

Comment: You do not say the wattage but probably 10 to tens of Watts. I'd VERY STRONGLY recommend that you web search for suitable circuits as a starting point. Your enthusiasm is commendable, but it is clear that the level of what you know means you will have a rather long development process. You can still get lots of DIY satisfaction following what others have done as a starting point. ||  555 based is doable but usually something using a "proper" switc hing inverter IC will make life far easier. | Higher frequency generally solves more problems than it makes.

Comment: Many starter ideas [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=diy+schematic+camera+flash+power+supply&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiVjqn9le_pAhXS0XMBHVukCRwQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=diy+schematic+camera+flash+power+supply&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1DZdFiZhwFgrYoBaABwAHgAgAHiAYgB3w2SAQUwLjguMpgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1n&sclient=img&ei=_ZXcXtWbGtKjz7sP28im4AE&bih=640&biw=1517&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ800AU800)

Comment: Go for [this one](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/mmCch9D3wkas1GRXRJAzmSCrsVkzW9YCHeSsRRRk4Hk-GCWwAUdXAu-DDJTCExRFVK3kjUKcIx8t6-GIxf5O53UPwoME) and be prepared to waste a few transistors in the process.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions! My current level of electronics understanding only comes from physics and so these are great resources to learn more of the practical side!